# inner and outer margin misplacement in book

Tags: books

I am using the book style `\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}` but the title, index starting and all the capters have larger margin in the right proper of documents opening on the left. I tried to change the option to `\documentclass[11pt,openleft]{book}` but there is no change on the page positioning.

Another option is to change the margins definition using this:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=3.5cm,outer=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

but it seems like an improper work-around to me. I'm sure there is a way to properly set it from the book class already.

Is there any other parameter to tune? or sould I apply the geometry solution and forget aobut it?

Comment: The larger margins are usually on the outer side; the difference is *not* for taking the binding into account.

Comment: Therefore in that case if I want to take the binding into account I've to impose it with the geometry package. However i still don't get the null effect of changing the parameter      `openright` to `openleft`

Comment: `openleft` and `openright` has nothing to do with the margins.

Comment: There is no `openleft` option with the `book` class.